# Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'borderProminent'

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I don't what I'm missing. I tried to follow online tutorial but I get error "Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'borderProminent" when I tried to add the three codes of the button below. Thank you for your help.

```
         Button(action: 
          
            {
            isOnboardingViewActive = true}) 

            {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.circle.fill")
                .imageScale(.large)
            
            Text("Reload")
                .font(.system(.title3, design: .rounded))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
               
        } // : BUTTON
        .buttonStyle(.borderProminent)
        .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
        .controlSize(.large)
```

Comment: Typo: `borderedProminent`, not `borderProminent`

Comment: I also tried but there's still an error " Reference to member 'buttonBorderedShape' cannot be resolved without a contextual type"

Comment: Not reproducible for me. Code compiles fine on Xcode 13.1

Comment: Try deleting the DerivedData for this project and clean the build folder. Sometimes those errors linger there.

Comment: I did clean the folder and it fix the problem. Thank you, I appreciate it :)